# How can I get events of a Facebook UID?

Tags: facebook, events, search

I am developing a web site with the `PHP Facebook SDK`.
I get all the events of a place by graph and show them on the site by with code:

```
$evt=$facebook->api('/search?fields=name,description,location,start_time,end_time&q='.urlencode($var[0]).'+'.$_GET['tipo'].'&type=event&limit=500&since=today&until='.$dq);
```

This works but I have this problem: with the web site I also get with the Facebook login  the Facebook ID of a web user and store its id into my `MySQL` Database table `pnota_USERS`.

To get all the events of the Facebook ID stored in my Database I use this code:

```
$db_host=modGoogleResHelper::db_host($params);
$db_pass=modGoogleResHelper::db_pass($params);
$db_user=modGoogleResHelper::db_user($params);
$db_name=modGoogleResHelper::db_name($params);


$db=mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die("errore nella connessione al database");

mysql_select_db(db_name);
$query="select * from pnota_users where facebook_id<>'' or facebook_id<>null";
$riga="";
$ret=mysql_query($query,$db);
if(mysql_affected_rows()>0){
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($ret))
{
$riga.=$row['facebook_id'].";";
}
mysql_free_result($ret);
}
$query="";
$rrx=explode(";",$riga);

foreach($rrx as $kkx)
{
if($kkx!="")
{
$zzz= $facebook->api('/'.$kkx.'/events', 'get', array("fields"=>"id, owner, name,location"));
print_r($zzz);
$fql = "SELECT name, location, start_time,end_time,eid FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid =".$kkx.") and start_time >='".$today."' and start_time<='".$tomorrow."' order by start_time desc" ;
$ret_objxx = $facebook->api(array(
'method'    =>'fql.query',
'req_perms' => 'friends_events,publish_stream,read_friendlists,email,user_events,manage_friendlists,rsvp_event,manage_notifications,user_online_presence',
'query'     => $fql) );

foreach($ret_objxx as $keyxx)
    {
$item=array("eid" => keyxx[eid],"name"=>'.',"start_time"=>$keyxx[start_time],"end_time"=>$keyxx[end_time],"timezone"=>'-',"location"=>$keyxx[location]);
array_push($events,$item);
    }
    }
    }
```

This FQL doesn't show me results.
I try to  put the query FQL directly to the Graph API Explorer :
In the Graph API Explorer if I choose in the top-right, the application Graph API Explorer   it show me results.
If  I choose in the Graph API Explorer in the top-right, the application Graph API Explorer `iprimanota` that is the name of my application it doesn't show me results.

My question is this:

I use bad permiss

Comment: why i haven't results by fql?

Comment: can i get events of an user id facebook that is not my friend? by php sdk?

Comment: $facebook->api('/******/events');